# Passing Bash variables to an awk script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am trying to get a bash script to use the username I give it. Put the Username as a variable and pass it to my awk script, so I can display the user's info in the manner I put it in my awk script. 
This is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Username:" $user 

 awk -v var="$user" -f passwd.awk /etc/passwd
```

AWK Script

```
BEGIN { FS = ":" }

if (var == $1){
    print ""
    print "UserName:"$1 
    print "Password Encrytped:"$2
    print "User Number:"$3 
    print "User Group:" $4
    print "FullName:" $5
    print "User Directory:" $6
    print "User Shell:" $7
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of :

```
read -p "Username:" $user
```

Use:

```
read -p "Username: " user
```

You need to provide a variable's name to `read` not its value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose your awk `if` statement in a block

```
BEGIN { FS = ":" }

{
    if (var == $1){
        print ""
        print "UserName:"$1 
        print "Password Encrypted:"$2
        print "User Number:"$3 
        print "User Group:" $4
        print "FullName:" $5
        print "User Directory:" $6
        print "User Shell:" $7
     }
}
```

You also need [anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23551450/900873), removing the sigil (`$`) on the `read` line.

Comment: Or remove the `if`: `$1 == var { print ... }`

Comment: Thank you, guys for helping me with my problem. It is much appreciated.

Comment: @user3618007 please click the check box under the down arrow in one of these answers like this one. Your reputation will increase as a result and tell everyone this question was answered.